# Use of Windows symlinks with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff, epsg

In my workspace I have a folder with a large amount of *.tif files. They are without header, so without spatial reference. From that I made symlinks to these files in 2 separate locations. In first location I added corresponding *.tfw files for EPSG:32633 and in second location *.tfw files for EPSG:3794. This kind of structure works for me and I'm using symlinks to save space on disk. In ArcGIS Pro I made two different personal geodatabases, one for each EPSG, and in each a Mosaic Dataset based on symlinks.

How do symlinks work with ArcGIS Pro? Can I for example simultaneously run processes like Build Pyramids on both Mosaic Datasets even though symlinks point to same root data? Will there be some lock on data either from filesystem, ArcGIS Pro or something else?

Comment: Personal geodatabases?  ArcGIS Pro cannot work with personal geodatabases.

Comment: @bixb0012 sorry, I meant File Geodatabase.

Comment: @SonofaBeach Exactly, there aren't any changes made to the original TIFF files, I was just afraid that while reading them some lock might happen and stop my process. I'm not planing on deleting anything so locks to prevent that don't bother me. Thank you for clearing this up for me!

Comment: (Moved my earlier comment to an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then the symlinks are only for the original TIFF file and nothing you're doing is going to write any changes to that original file. If that is the case, then there would be no such locks, and all the file-handles that would be opened  to the original TIFF file by your processing and use of mosaic datasets would be read-only.

It could create file locks that prevent you from deleting or moving the original TIFF file while some process has it open. But should not be anything preventing multiple processes from reading it simultaneously.